# Drupal State API - set key expired time

Tags: caching, drupal-8

I am new to Drupal 8. I have found Drupal state API for cache mechanism. Can I set key expire time also with below statement?

\Drupal::state()->set('key','value');

Source : https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/state-api/overview

Here I am able to set key but I want to clear it after 60 minutes. 
Is there any other cache mechanism I can use?

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `State` directly, you can use your own wrapper that uses the `KeyValueExpirableFactoryInterface`. See the Drupal docs for more about the [KeyValueStore API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/namespace/Drupal%21Core%21KeyValueStore/8.6.x).

Example:

```
$kvStorage = \Drupal::service('keyvalue.expirable')->get('my_collection_name');
$kvStorage->setWithExpire('my_key', 'my_value', time() + 3600);
```

Also, [this article from Palantir](https://www.palantir.net/blog/d8ftw-storing-data-drupal-8) has a good overview of the various data-storage APIs in Drupal 8 and what they are best for.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is incorrect. You specify the length of time in seconds from the current request. If you call time(), you're telling Drupal to store the value for a very, very, very long time.

```
// Get the key value collection
$kv_store = \Drupal::service('keyvalue.expirable')->get('my_module_name');

// Get the value or null
$token = $kv_store->get('token', null);

// If no value, set the value
if (!$token) {
  $kv_storage->setWithExpire('token', 'my_token', 3600);
}
```